# Is 'Brie' a proper noun?

Tags: nouns, terminology

*Brie* is defined in [this Oxford Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/brie) as follows:

> A kind of soft, mild, creamy cheese with a firm white skin.
>
> **Origin**
>
> Named after Brie in northern France, where it was originally made.

Some relevant example sentences from the dictionary include:

> *Soft cheeses such as **Brie**, feta, and Camembert may have bacteria that can cause infections.*
>
> *Creamy **Brie**, buttery croissants, indulgent pastries are just part of the French paradox.*
>
> *It's not as soft as **Brie**, not as sharp as Bleu, and not as hard as Parmesan.*
>
> *Tasty though **Brie** and other cheeses are, there is little to recommend them from a nutritional perspective.*
>
> *The fastest growing varieties include Gorgonzola or Asiago, goat cheese or **Brie**.*

Now, the term 'proper noun' is defined in [the same dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/proper_noun) as follows:

> A name used for an individual person, place, or organization, spelled with an initial capital letter, e.g. *Jane*, *London*, and *Oxfam*.

I'm sure *Brie* in its original sense of a city in France is a proper noun, because it is a name used for an individual place, spelled with an initial capital letter. But how about *Brie* as a kind of cheese?

Is *Brie* as a kind of cheese also a proper noun under this definition?

If not, should the definition be modified to accommodate *Brie* the kind of cheese as a proper noun? Or is *Brie* the kind of cheese not a proper noun?

Comment: Aren't you really just asking whether it should be capitalized?

Comment: @tchrist Not really. As you can see in the 20 example sentences in the dictionary, _Brie_ the cheese is always capitalized. Also I don't think that capitalization is a necessary and sufficient condition for a proper noun, because common nouns used in proper names are also capitalized, e.g., _the United Kingdom_.

Comment: You haven't done your research: a single dictionary definition isn't enough. My web search for "define proper noun" immediately comes up with [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/proper-noun), [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/proper-nouns/), [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proper%20noun) and [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/proper-noun) all defining the term to include ***things***. I'm voting to close for lack of research.

Comment: @Chappo First, just because those definitions include 'thing' (not 'things' as you claim), does that mean _Brie_ is a proper noun? Can you honestly say that a kind of cheese is a "particular thing"?? Second, I didn't claim that I've looked at all the dictionaries in the world, or that the Oxford definition is the correct one no matter what. I even asked if the definition should be modified to accommodate _Brie_ the kind of cheese as a proper noun. If you feel that to merely include 'thing' in the definition would make a difference, you should write up an answer instead of voting to close.

Comment: Brie (the cheese) is an eponym, and in my earlier link Grammarly notes that some eponyms lose their capitalisation over time, e.g. *sandwich*. But the 3 dictionaries I linked to all capitalise Brie, and if an eponym is capitalised it's necessarily a proper noun (though Collins offers "also **brie**", denoting a variant usage as a common noun). In my view it would be wrong to close a question *and* slip an answer in first, but if your question doesn't get closed, I'll expand my comment to an answer.

Comment: Alternatively, why not [edit] your question to ask how you can tell whether a word - such as Brie/brie - should be capitalised, especially when there conflicting usages? You might also add in other brand names such as heroin, linoleum, hoover, biro, google: at what point does uncapitalised usage become so common that it must be accepted as a *common* noun, despite brand owner legal action?

Comment: @Chappo I don't really understand people like yourself who seem dedicated more to closing questions than answering them. It's not like this site is without garbage questions that are not closed. I think like more than half the questions being asked in this site are pure garbage, most of which are not even attempted to be closed by even you. // Re this specific question, you don't understand the call of the question. It's not all about it being capitalized or not. Please re-read the question.

Comment: @JK2 Your Qn is in the [Review Queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) but I didn't put it there. Once you get the rep points, you too can have the pleasure of wading through all the "garbage" questions (as you put it) & cast votes to close them. There's 200 questions in the Close queue & it takes 5 users to close a question, so just to clear *today's* queue we need 1000 votes! But not all Qns in the queue should be closed; maybe yours won't be. Ask better Qns, earn enough pts, start helping us remove the "garbage". :-)

Answer (score -1):

Brie, the cheese, is a proper noun in France, where the use of the term is defined by law; elsewhere it’s a common noun.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brie:

> There are now many varieties of brie made all over the world, including plain brie, herbed varieties, double and triple brie and versions of brie made with other types of milk. Indeed, although brie is a French cheese, it is possible to obtain Somerset and Wisconsin brie. Despite the variety of bries, the French government officially certifies only two types of cheese to be sold under that name: Brie de Meaux and Brie de Melun.

Comment: I think you have the beginnings of an excellent answer. But, I don't think the answer lies in country of origin making it a proper noun. Rather, it just forces capitalizion due to its being an appellation controlled by law that contains a proper noun as a demonym.

Comment: @David the distinction being 'it's only capitalised because the French government want it to'? (And if they officialised the lowercase version, that would be 'correct'?)

Comment: @David M Sounds good to me. Feel free to do something more complete. The EU has regs, but countries are allowed to have additional rules. And there are trademarks.

Comment: In your quote, I think they really are treating 'brie' as a common noun. But that's perhaps because it is being treated as a class having different subcategories? (A common noun denotes a class.)

Comment: I disagree with the idea of a class as defining a noun. It’s an imposition of logic on language.

Comment: Language itself is not logic. But you can't possibly discuss language without any logic. The very reason that all major languages have common nouns is in order not to have to have a name for everything and require a virtually infinite number of nouns.

Comment: @marcellothearcane In short, yes. In France (and the EU), the name of the cheese has been determined by law. Can't seem to drop the wiki for appellation controlee laws.

Comment: -1 for "elsewhere it’s a common noun", which you've provided no evidence for. Collins, M-W and Dictionary.com all list *Brie* in capitalised form, i.e. as a proper noun.

Answer (score -1):

On the subject of *capital letters*, The [Guardian newspaper's style guide](https://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2011/feb/24/mind-your-language-cornish-pasties) says,

> "Words and phrases based on proper names that have lost connection
>   with their origins (alsatian dog, cardigan, cheddar cheese, french
>   windows, wellington boots, yorkshire pudding and many others) are
>   lowercase. Those that retain a strong link, which may be legally
>   recognised, include Cornish pasty, Melton Mowbray pork pies, Parma ham
>   and Worcestershire sauce, and take initial cap. **Although champagne is
>   legally required to come from Champagne, it is almost universally
>   regarded as lc.** If in doubt, see individual entries for food and
>   wines".

I think champagne - with a small c - has to be a common noun. Your dictionary evidently considers Brie to have retained a strong link with its origins but the online dictionaries differ. I found this on https://www.chihuahua-puzzle.com/forum/index.php?topic=1090.10;wap2 :

> (If we regard Edam as a noun meaning a type of cheese - which is how dictionaries define it - then it is certainly not a proper name, even if written with a capital letter. Quite a lot of texts use the phrase Edam cheese, in which context Edam might be regarded as naming the place, as London does in London bus.)
>
> A more thorough investigation reveals that there are a couple of
>   Oxford dictionaries that list edam in all lower-case: The New Zealand
>   Oxford Dictionary and The Australian Oxford Dictionary. All the other
>   Oxford editions seem to use a capital E. (Thanks to my Melbourne
>   Library Service membership, I have access to Oxford Reference Online.)
>   These same two dictionaries list brie with a lower-case b. The
>   Canadian Oxford Dictionary has an each-way bet, with brie and Edam.

Perhaps it is up to you to view Brie as proper or common. I shall carry on thinking no piece of cheese can be a proper noun, but I'll still spell it with a capital.

Comment: There's a problem with viewing _Brie_ the kind of cheese as a proper noun in that "a kind of cheese" is not "a name used for an individual person, place, or organization" (as defined by the Oxford Dictionary), assuming that the definition is correct. // _Brie_ is not a piece of cheese but a kind of cheese.